# Error decoding a javascript json from php

Tags: php, json

I'm having problems decoding from php a json created with javascript JSON.stringfy. Maybe the problem is that the object has arrays.
The JSON and the core are:

```
$jsonString = "{"tabLabels":["tab1","tab2","tab3","tab4","tab5"],"tabBgs":["21","2","3","0","4"],"tabPublico":[0,0,1,1,0],"fuente":"2","size":"17px"}";

$jsonObj = json_decode($jsonString);

echo $jsonObj->obj;
$tabs = $jsonObj->tabPublico
for ($i=0;$i<strlen($tabs);$i++)
{
   echo $tabs[i];
}
```

The "echoes" don't show anything.

Thank you for your help.
Oscar.

Comment: Is that your code? If so, your JSON string is badly escaped.

Comment: @Florent, His JSON is good.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran You know what I mean (see your answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These were your mistakes.

- Enclose your **`$jsonString`** with single quote
- You missed a semicolon **`;`** on the 6th line.
- You are using **`strlen()`** instead of **`count()`**.

---

Modified code.

```
<?php
$jsonString = '{"tabLabels":["tab1","tab2","tab3","tab4","tab5"],"tabBgs":["21","2","3","0","4"],"tabPublico":[0,0,1,1,0],"fuente":"2","size":"17px"}';

$jsonObj = json_decode($jsonString);
$tabs = $jsonObj->tabPublico;
foreach($tabs as $k=>$v)
{
echo $v;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
00110
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers Shankar and Deepu. I've simplified here my code to focus in the problem and I've had a couple of errors, the jsonString is readed from sql it's not a fixed local var like the example, then I don't have the quote errors and semicolons. But your answers helped me a lot, I've had wrong the loop and I've had a wrong echo that spoiled the outpout. Thanks a lot!

Comment: (I've voted up offcourse, I don't know anything about the downvote)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.You json was badly escaped and for an array you must use `count()` to find the length of array to loop through.

```
$jsonString = '{"tabLabels":["tab1","tab2","tab3","tab4","tab5"],"tabBgs":["21","2","3","0","4"],"tabPublico":[0,0,1,1,0],"fuente":"2","size":"17px"}';
$jsonObj = json_decode($jsonString);
$tabs = $jsonObj->tabPublico;
for($i=0;$i<count($tabs);$i++)
{
   echo $tabs[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$jsonString = '{"tabLabels":["tab1","tab2","tab3","tab4","tab5"],"tabBgs":["21","2","3","0","4"],"tabPublico":[0,0,1,1,0],"fuente":"2","size":"17px"}'
```

pass JSON string under single quotes.